# Prolog logical programming Binary tree predicates

Tags: prolog

I am a total beginner to logic programming and Prolog so the problem is that i am trying to implement a binary tree in Prolog which i did like this:

```
tree(-). 
tree(n(X,L,R)):- tree(L), tree(R).
```

now i need to implement the following predicates

`count(X,Tree,Res).` which should count how many times X is given in the passed tree and return it in Res.

`sum(Tree, Sum).` which should return the Sum of all Nodes in the passed tree if Numerical. 
My idea for this one was something like this:

```
treeSum([],0).
treeSum(tree(X,T1,T2), S) :-
   treeSum(T1,S1),
   treeSum(T2,S2),
   S is X + S1 + S2.
```

`replace(X , Y, TreeIn , TreeOut).` which should swap every Node containing X with Y 
in TreeIn and return TreeOut.

Answer (score 3):

A binary tree is just a data structure. I would represent it as something like `tree(L,R,V)`, where

- `L` is the left subtree,
- `R` is the right subtree, and
- `V` is the value of that node.

Taking a cue from how lists are represented in Prolog, we can use an atom `nil` to represent a non-existent subtree, so a leaf node would look like this `tree(nil,nil,123)` So, for a tree that looks like this:

```
     4
    / \
   2   5
  / \   \
 1   3   6
```

you would have this Prolog structure:

```
tree(
  tree(
    tree(
      .,
      .,
      1
    ),
    tree(
      .,
      .,
      2
    ),
    3
  ),
  tree(
    .,
    tree(
      .,
      .,
      6
    ),
    5
  ),
  4
)
```

Then it's a simple matter of walking the tree to do what you want. For instance,

```
sum( nil         , 0 ).
sum( tree(L,R,V) , S ) :-
  sum( L , SumL ),
  sum( R , SumR ),
  S is V + SumL + SumR
  .

count( _, nil, 0 ). 
count( X, tree(L,R,V), C) :-
  count(X,L,Lefts),
  count(X,R,Rights),
  ( X = V -> N = 1 ; N = 0 ) ,
  C is N  + Lefts + Rights.
```

Sandbox is at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/ncarey-binary-tree.pl

Comment: the OP says `tree(T) :- T=n(X,L,R) ; T='-'.`, you're saying `tree(T):- T=tree(L,R,V); T=nil.`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, my tree data structure has to be implemented this way tree(n(X,L,R)) :- tree(L), tree(R), tree(L,R,V) is not allowed.